# How Can I use error function in Nuxt Plugin?

Tags: plugins, error-handling, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt and [axios-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module).

I trying to global error handling by axios global interceptor.

How Can I use error function in Nuxt Plugin?

```
// ~/plugins/axios.js

export default function ({ $axios, store, redirect, error }) {
 $axios
 .onError(apiError => {
   error({statusCode: '403', message: 'test'}) // It's not work.
   redirect('http://google.com') // It's work.
  })
}
```

redirect is working. but error not work. just display [server error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O5T4.png).

Comment: It works. It show u are a debug page for 403 error

Comment: @Aldarund
I know that an error function will redirect to a custom error page. In the middleware, the error function redirect to the custom error page.

Comment: dont understand. U are calling error with 403 code. And u are seeing as a result error page for 403 code. What do u expect?

Comment: @Aldarund I want to redirect 'custom' error page on error interceptor by error function.

Comment: then u just need to customize your error page layout/error.vue

Comment: @Aldarund I did. and I try to redirect customized error page by error function. but It's not work in plugin js file.

Comment: I've got same error.. Any answers yet? T.T

Comment: Not sure if you are still having this issue, but our axios plugin uses the context error function:
```
    $axios.onError(err => {
        const code = parseInt(err.response && err.response.status);
        app.context.error({ statusCode: code });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Now it's available in [@nuxtjs/axios Helper](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers)

```js
export default function ({ $axios, error: nuxtError }) {
  $axios.onError(error => {
    nuxtError({
      statusCode: error.response.status,
      message: error.message,
    });
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

After checking my code.I found that when you request data only once in asyncData method, the error methods in plugin works. However, if you request several times, error method may not work. This method cannot stop returning data in asyncData method.

So, my solution is check the response both in the axios plugin you build and also check the response when you request several api with promise.all(). if not qualified, stop return data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin function should return a promise and resolved just after calling the `error` function because Nuxt.js treat plugin function like a promise. Just like this.

```js
export default function ({ $axios, error }) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    $axios.onError(apiError => {
      error({ statusCode: 403, message: 'test' }))
      resolve()
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Axios helper for Nuxt errors that help to handle interceptions.

```
export default function ({ $axios, store, redirect, error: nuxtError }) {
  $axios.onError(error => {
    nuxtError({
      statusCode: error.response.status,
      message: error.message,
      if(statusCode === 403){
        redirect('http://example.com')
      }
    });
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  })
}
```

See [@nuxt/axios helpers](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers/) for details and for more about that see [extending axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend/)