# how to handle axios error unifiedly in asyncData() in SSR nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to handle axios errors unifiedly when the response's status code is not **2XX** or **3XX**.

For example, requests for captchas, the backend will return **429** status code if there are too many requests in a short time sent from one client.

#### ***models/Captcha.js***

```js
import axios from 'axios';
class Captcha{
    static async store(){
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/auth/captchas`);
        return data;
    }
}
export default Captcha;
```

#### ***plugins/axios-interceptor.js***

```js
import axios from 'axios';

// after getting response
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        // handle errors unifiedly here
        handleErrors(error);
    }
);
```

in `nuxt.config.js`

```
    plugins:[
        '~/plugins/axios-interceptor'
    ],
```

#### ***pages/register.vue***

```js
<template>
    ...
    <img :src="captcha.image_content" @click="refreshCaptcha()">
    ...
</template>
import Captcha from '@/models/Captcha';
export default{
    async asyncData(){
        const captcha = await Captcha.store();
        return {
            captcha: captcha
        }
    },
    methods:{
        async refreshCaptcha(){
            this.captcha = await Captcha.store();
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

But it can't work as I expected.

1. First, I don't want to have the default errors handler by *Nuxt.js*
   [image]
2. Second, it can't handle errors happened in `node.js`, I want to render the page normally when errors occurred
   [image]

How can I solve it? I don't want to use callback instead of Promise or async function, because the Nuxt.js Official said they will not support it any longer in the future.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use `try/catch` in `asynData`.

Comment: @BeHappy Thank you! But this can't avoid `Nuxt.js` default errors handler, what I want is when errors happened the page can still be rendered and only the code in `handleErrors()` will be ran

Comment: Can you share your `try/catch`?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @vinni Yeah, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65606456/10519069) your can see

Answer (score 1):

The asyncData command runs on the server side and you can not use the methods and services you wrote on the client side in asyncData. In fact, the contents of asyncData are called before your project loads.